# Giving a class to an element when it triggers a slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a jQuery slider which uses little thumbnails in the bottom left and allows the users to click on the thumbnails to trigger certain slides.

I would like to give the selected thumbnails a new class when selected so essentially giving having them sync up with the slides.

Is this possible?

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startGallery() {
var myGallery = new gallery($('myGallery'), {
timed: true
});
}
window.addEvent('domready', startGallery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, You have to edit the `gallery` function. And add this jQuery function `$('your-element-id').addClass("Your-New-Class noClass");` on successful selection of a thumbnail. And do not forget to remove the selected class from all the thumbnail before adding the selection class using `$('your-all-thumb-element-class').removeClass("Your-New-Class");`. And do not forget to assign different `id` to all thumb elements.

Comment: How does this feature allow the Slide and the Thumbnail to synch up? Do I add this to my header or to a .js file?

Comment: Yeah you have to add this to your `a.js` file wher you have stored your `gallery` function. And make sure to add this code on right place, I mean after the animation is completed.